# Amazon API Request

Tags: json, api, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to understand how am I sending product request for amazon.
The example in the AWS look like this:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService
&Operation=ItemSearch
&ResponseGroup=Small
&Keywords=Engagement%20ring%20set
&Availability=Available
&SearchIndex=Jewelry
&AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
&AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyId]
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

I got in my ID but I can't get the request.

I'm getting ERROR 404.

Maybe AssociateTag? Where I can get him?

Thanks

Comment: `404` means "not found" which usually means you're callign the wrong endpoint.

Comment: please explain, its the first time in use the AWS

Comment: are you using API gateway?